# Add class to specific element in React onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use react-slick carousel with custom controls. I want to add 'active' class only to element that is changes the slide (by onClick event). But in my case 'active' class toggles for all of them.

```
export default class ServicesSlider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.changeSlide = this.changeSlide.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            isActive: false
        }
    }
    changeSlide(e) {
        this.setState({
            isActive: !this.state.isActive
        });
        this.slider.slickGoTo(e);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <section className="carousel-controls">
                    <div
                        onClick={() => this.changeSlide(0)}
                        className={this.state.isActive
                        ? 'column' : 'column active'}>Slide one
                    </div>
                    <div
                        onClick={() => this.changeSlide(1)}
                        className={this.state.isActive
                        ? 'column' : 'column active'}>Slide two
                    </div>
                    <div
                        onClick={() => this.changeSlide(2)}
                        className={this.state.isActive
                        ? 'column' : 'column active'}>Slide three
                    </div>
                    <div
                        onClick={() => this.changeSlide(3)}
                        className={this.state.isActive
                        ? 'column' : 'column active'}>Slide four
                    </div>
                </section>
                <Slider ref={c => this.slider = c}>
                    <div className="sliderItem">Slide 1</div>
                    <div className="sliderItem">Slide 2</div>
                    <div className="sliderItem">Slide 3</div>
                    <div className="sliderItem">Slide 4</div>
                </Slider>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

How to properly append class to a specific element in React?

Comment: maintain a state array of active class instead of a single state

Comment: You are passing an index to changeSlide, but only toggling the active state. The state will therefore be a boolean, true or false, instead of an integer representing the currently active element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is to not keep track of a boolean `active`, but of the active index. That is, which slide is active: `0, 1, 2, 3, or 4, ...`. You will need to modify your state to achieve that.

I would also advocate changing the parameter from `e` to something more descriptive, as `e` is generally used for events.

If you change your state to

```
this.state = {
    activeIndex: 0
}
```

then you can update the active value as such:

```
changeSlide(index) {
    this.setState({
        activeIndex: index
    });
    this.slider.slickGoTo(index);
}
```

and then check for active in render:

```
<div
    onClick={() => this.changeSlide(0)}
    className={this.state.activeIndex !== 0 ? 'column' : 'column active'}>
    Slide one
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than having an `isActive` variable, which suggests only a true/false value, why not have a `currentActiveSlide` variable?

In the constructor you initiate it as `null` (if you want your App to start with no active slide). And then update it with the index when you click it.

So your `changeSlide()` function becomes:

```
changeSlide(idx) {
  // If we click on the already active slide, set "currentActiveSlide" to null.
  // Otherwise, set it to the "idx".
  this.setState({
    currentActiveSlide: idx !== this.state.currentActiveSlide ? idx : null
  });
  this.slider.slickGoTo(idx);
}
```

I changed your `e` parameter to `idx` for clarity. because the former suggests an event. Of course, you would need to update your render as well:

```
className={this.state.currentActiveSlide === 1 ? 'column' : 'column active'}
```

(though I think you got the logic reversed here).

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the same state name in all the slides. I suggest creating an array as this.state.isActive, and having each slide be a different index of that array. Then you just change the array index onClick

```
export default class ServicesSlider extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.changeSlide = this
        .changeSlide
        .bind(this)
    this.state = {
        isActive: Array(4).fill(false); //new stuff
    }
}
changeSlide(e) {
    const newBool = !this.state.isActive[e]; //new stuff
    var newArray = this.state.isActive;//new stuff
    newArray[e] = (newBool);//new stuff
    this.setState({
        isActive: newArray//new stuff
    });
    this
        .slider
        .slickGoTo(e);
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <section className="carousel-controls">
                <div
                    onClick={() => this.changeSlide(0)}
                    className={this.state.isActive[0]//new stuff
                    ? 'column'
                    : 'column active'}>Slide one
                </div>
                <div
                    onClick={() => this.changeSlide(1)}
                    className={this.state.isActive[1]//new stuff
                    ? 'column'
                    : 'column active'}>Slide two
                </div>
                <div
                    onClick={() => this.changeSlide(2)}
                    className={this.state.isActive[2]//new stuff
                    ? 'column'
                    : 'column active'}>Slide three
                </div>
                <div
                    onClick={() => this.changeSlide(3)}
                    className={this.state.isActive[3]//new stuff
                    ? 'column'
                    : 'column active'}>Slide four
                </div>
            </section>
            <Slider ref={c => this.slider = c}>
                <div className="sliderItem">Slide 1</div>
                <div className="sliderItem">Slide 2</div>
                <div className="sliderItem">Slide 3</div>
                <div className="sliderItem">Slide 4</div>
            </Slider>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be :

```
this.setState({
    activeSlide: e
});
```

Then use:

```
className={this.state.activeSlide === {x} ? 'column' : 'column active'}
```